# Good portable wiimote library with sound support?

Tags: c, portability, wiimote

I'm lookin for a portable wiimote library.  I want to use the wiimote for the hardware it has (but I don't need to access any data stored on it).

Required features:

- access to all the buttons (as an exception, no use of the power button is OK)
- make the wiimote play sound
- talk to nunchuks and classic controllers
- preferably: make the wiimote rumble.
- interface with C.  Preferably native C.  Bonus points for bindings with Haskell or python.

The library should port to Linux, Windows and OS X (in order of importance) and should be agnostic with respect to CPU architecture.

Anyone got a good suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't use it (I've only read about the managed Wiimote library really), but you may want to check out [wiiuse](http://www.wiiuse.net/). It seems like the most complete of the native libararies.

Others include:

- [GlovePIE](http://carl.kenner.googlepages.com/glovepie_download)
- [WiiYourself](http://wiiyourself.gl.tter.org/)

Comment: beware of GlovePie - the license has some weird restrictions

Comment: @Richard Are you talking about the "Global Warming" thing they have and 100% Green Power? It says it isn't a licence restriction, but just alerting you that you are destroying the plannet... it's weird but not the EULA. *"This is not a license restriction, just a restriction imposed by the laws of physics. Don't shoot the messenger."* The things inside quotes are copied directly from http://glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my WiiMouse program to do this (which is based on the wiimotelib open source project), it allows you to connect via named pipes and play PCM sounds and use all the attachments including the MotionPlus, it even calculates the MotionPLus vectors for you, you can get it here:

http://home.exetel.com.au/amurgshere/wiimouse.phtml

See the download for an example on how to connect to a wiimote via named pipes and play sounds and stuff.